# Linux Red Hat Bash is directory error , trying to divide one file value from another in Red Hat VI

Tags: linux

I am trying to using the following code for this problem , and it keeps giving me a bash is directory error in Red Hat:

```
#!/bin/bash
expr'cat file2'/'cat file1'>file3
touch file1 file2 file3
```

~
**This is the problem**
In the same folder as last week, create a new file called week3prog3[name].scr.

Change the permissions on this new file to add the execute bit for user, group, and owner.

Create two files.

•   File1 has one line with the value of 5.
•   File2 has one line with the value of 100.

Edit your new file using Gedit or VI and change it so it performs the following actions:

•   Read the values from the two files above (file1 and file2). 
•   Divide the value from file2 by the value in file1.
•   Output the result of this calculation to a new file called file3.

Note. Remember to include #!/bin/bash as the first line of your script.

Comment: Replace the first line with `#!/bin/bash -vx` to debug your script.

Comment: Your shell script is bad formatted. It lacks an space after `expr`. Also, do you know the difference between simple, double or execute quotes in shell? You are using simple, when you must use execute back-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You might want backquotes, or shell substitution. So perhaps code

```
 expr "$(cat file2)/$(cat file1)">file3
```

but that is probably still wrong (but I don't understand what you want to achieve). Read the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), and temporarily replace the first line with `#!/bin/bash -vx` to debug your script.

Comment: this still is not working , when I do that it gives me 100/5 when I need 20 as the result

Comment: I did tell it is probably wrong, but I do want you to read the advanced bash scripting guide.